# Graylog docker image bound to internal IP instead of 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, graylog2, graylog

Based on the instructions on Graylog docker, I have the following `docker-compose.yml` to run the Graylog stack:

```yaml
version: '2'
volumes:
  es_data:
  mongo_data:
  graylog_journal:
services:
  # MongoDB: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
  # Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.12
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - network.host=127.0.0.1
      # Disable X-Pack security: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/security-settings.html#general-security-settings
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
  # Graylog: https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog/
  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:2.4.6-1
    volumes:
      - graylog_journal:/usr/share/graylog/data/journal
      - ./graylog/config:/usr/share/graylog/data/config
    environment:
      # CHANGE ME!
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
      # Password: admin
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://0.0.0.0:9000/api
      - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_ENABLED=true
      - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_PORT=25
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      # Graylog web interface and REST API
      - 9000:9000
      # Syslog TCP
      - 514:514
      # Syslog UDP
      - 514:514/udp
      # GELF TCP
      - 12201:12201
      # GELF UDP
      - 12201:12201/udp
```

From the logs of the container, I can see it claims service bound to 0.0.0.0

```
2018-11-30 02:51:09,503 INFO : org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener - Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:9000]
2018-11-30 02:51:09,506 INFO : org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer - [HttpServer] Started.
2018-11-30 02:51:09,506 INFO : org.graylog2.shared.initializers.JerseyService - Started REST API at <http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/>
2018-11-30 02:51:09,507 INFO : org.graylog2.shared.initializers.JerseyService - Started Web Interface at <http://0.0.0.0:9000/>
```

But when I access the front end, it gives the following error:

```
Error message
Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
Original Request
GET http://172.24.0.4:9000/api/system/sessions
Status code
undefined
Full error message
Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's missing a configuration in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

`GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI: http//<publicip>:9000/api`

Seems have fixed the problem.